# How to read and process a HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-post, httphandler

I have a HTTP handler which receives a HTTP POST. HTTP POST message with header is -

```
POST /ibe/example.ashx HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; text/html; charset=GBK
Host: 202.177.46.142
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
```

`param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3`

Handler in my code is -

```
var V1 = context.Request["param1"];
var V2 = context.Request["param2"];
```

But values returning are `null`

Comment: Have you tried `Request.QueryString("param1")`?

Comment: We really need more context if you want help. Define _didn't work_ and include at least a snippet of your handler where it's _"not working"_.

Comment: `didn't work` can mean almost anything, so it tells us absolutely nothing about the issue you're having. Please be more specific.

Comment: One problem I see is your `Content-Length` header (27) doesn't match the length of your content (41).  Beyond that, there's no way to tell what might be wrong without more details.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a post I think you'd want to use a stream reader to get the body, then deserialize if needed.